# Should I use arrays or store separate values in separate columns?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, database-normalization

Specifically, I'm building an text-based RPG Application, but the question is this: what is the difference between using arrays and storing values separately.

Normally, If you want to get your 10th Monster, you say `select 10` but storing that number 10 is the problem.
Should I store the numbers in an array so when they `select 10` it selects the 10th element in the array OR store numbers in a different table so when they `select 10` it checks for the column with number 10 and which it's owner ID = the selectors' ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question.

**When is it a good idea to use arrays?**

- If you would otherwise end up with very many columns.
- If you never need to use array elements in `WHERE` or `JOIN` conditions.
- If you never need to modify array elements, only the array as a whole.

Usually arrays are a bad idea, because they violate the first normal form.

If you need to use array elements in `WHERE` conditions efficiently, or you want to modify individual array members, the suffering starts.

Arrays can be a good thing when used wisely, but if you look through the questions asked here, you'll find a good many by people who suffer from data models that abuse  compound data types like arrays or JSON.

Comment: I only need to use them in WHERE conditions (such as `SELECT monsters[1], monsters[2] FROM users WHERE user_id = {user_id}`, don't need to use JOIN conditions for the elements just yet, and I don't need to modify the specific elements. All I have to do is adding and removing elements from the array. So I guess it's safe to use them. And are Arrays faster?

Comment: Adding and removing elements from an array means rewriting the whole array. If that's ok for you, you can do it. I won't make any prediction about speed; that depends on too much and should be tested.

Comment: Okay, Thank you :)